# Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: Network request failed in expo

Tags: react-native, api

im trying to consume my api, here is  the code

here I create the home class and the state

```
 export default class  Home extends React.Component {
   state = {
     region: null,
     places: []
   }
```

here I connect to my api and try to search for the places

```
   async componentDidMount() {
     fetch('http://localhost:3000/auth/list')
       .then(res => res.json())
       .then(res =>{
         this.setState({
           places: res
      
         })
       })
```

here I render this in a map

```
 render() {
     const {region} = this.state;
     return (
       <View style={styles.Container}>
         <MapView style={styles.Mapview} 
         region={region}
         showsUserLocation={true}
         zoomEnabled={true}
         showsPointsOfInterest={false}
         initialRegion={region}
       
         >
```

here I create a marker

```
           {this.state.places.map(places => (
             <MapView.Marker
             key={places.id}
             title={places.title}
             description={places.description}
             coordinate={{
               latitude: places.latitude,
               longitude: places.longitude
             }}
        
             />
           ))}
         </MapView>
```

but it says :Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: Network request failed

Answer (score 0):

This will throw an error that should be caught using a catch function. Try this way

```
return fetch(url)
  .then(function (response) {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(function (res) {
    this.setState({
      places: res,
    });
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log("Error");
    // ADD THIS THROW error
    throw error;
  });
```